# Running export_inference_graph.py gives difference in types error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to export a model by executing export_inference_graph.py script.

I tried with my trained model.ckpt and official example files for ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.

In cmd I type:

```
python export_inference_graph.py \ --input_type image_tensor \ --pipeline_config_path training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config \ --trained_checkpoint_prefix training/model.ckpt-2453 \ --output_directory heart_graph
```

I am using TensorFlow 1.4 and I always get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "export_inference_graph.py", line 119, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 48, in run
    _sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
  File "export_inference_graph.py", line 115, in main
    FLAGS.output_directory, input_shape)
  File "C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\exporter.py", line 427, in export_inference_graph
    input_shape, optimize_graph, output_collection_name)
  File "C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\exporter.py", line 353, in _export_inference_graph
    postprocessed_tensors = detection_model.postprocess(output_tensors)
  File "C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\meta_architectures\ssd_meta_arch.py", line 405, in postprocess
    class_predictions_without_background)
  File "C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection\builders\post_processing_builder.py", line 94, in score_converter_fn
    scaled_logits = tf.divide(logits, logit_scale, name='scale_logits')
  File "C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 309, in divide
    return DivideDelegateWithName(x, name) / y
  File "C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 294, in __truediv__
    return _truediv_python3(self.x, y, self.name)
  File "C:\Users\<Name>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py", line 981, in _truediv_python3
    (x_dtype, y_dtype))
TypeError: x and y must have the same dtype, got tf.float32 != tf.int32
```

Where is the problem and how to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

recently I used `object detection` to do some interesting things, and occur this error too, I look up the issues on the github and find the solutions.

In the `https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/2774`, there is a solution that changed the source code, and I try it. It WORKS!!

You can find the `post_processing_builder.py`and change the function with

    `def _score_converter_fn_with_logit_scale(tf_score_converter_fn, logit_scale):
  """Create a function to scale logits then apply a Tensorflow function."""
  def score_converter_fn(logits):
    cr = logit_scale
    cr = tf.constant([[cr]],tf.float32)
    print(logit_scale)
    print(logits)
    scaled_logits = tf.divide(logits, cr, name='scale_logits') #change logit_scale
    return tf_score_converter_fn(scaled_logits, name='convert_scores')
  score_converter_fn.__name__ = '%s_with_logit_scale' % (
      tf_score_converter_fn.__name__)
  return score_converter_fn`

Then go to the `research` folder, run

`python setup.py install`

Then it will be OK!

By the way, I don't know whether you should re-install the `slim` in the `research` folder, you'd better re-install it too.

Comment: Thanks for the great suggestion, works as expected. Strange that this is still a bug.